# Trying to use dependent multi selection lists as filters in Shiny app

Tags: r, shiny

I have a shiny app that has a variety of filters for the user, including region and country. The choices for country depend on which region(s) are selected. This works, in the sense that when I select a region I see the correct countries. This works with this code in the server section:

```
observe({
    x <- regions %>%
        filter(country_region %in% input$region) %>%
        select(Country)
    updateSelectInput(session, "country", "Select countries", choices = unique(x))
})
```

Then later I want to filter a data frame for the region and country choices. First, I filter the data frame only on the region, because I want the user to be able to pick a region and get all results for all countries (user has to press a button to update results, which is the `input$go`):

```
give_data <- eventReactive(input$go, {
        message(exists("input$country"))
        message(input$country)
        prod_a_domains <- corp_dat %>%
            filter(country_region %in% input$region)
```

This gives me the data filtered for the region, and, when I do not select a country, those two messages are `FALSE` (`input$country` does not exist) and blank (no value for it).

Next, I want to filter for country if there is a country selection. I try to do that with:

```
    if (!exists("input$country")) {
        message("met condition, no country filter")
        prod_a_domains <- prod_a_domains %>%
            select(email_domain) %>%
            distinct()
    } else {
        message("did not meet, filtering")
        prod_a_domains <- filter(prod_a_domains, Country %in% input$country) %>%
            select(email_domain) %>%
            distinct()
    }
```

I believe this would work, the problem is that `exists("input$country")` still resolves to `FALSE` even after I make a country selection, but `message(input$country)` does tell me the country name that I've selected. So the if logic doesn't process correctly, it always follows the first path rather than the ELSE condition regardless of whether or not I've selected a country. There's something going on that I don't understand about the "existence" of that object at that point in time.

Comment: try replacing `!exists("input$country")` with `is.null(input$country)`

Comment: that did it. so if the object is defined in the UI, it exists; but is created with a null value. Is that what I was missing?

Comment: BTW if you want to make that an answer I'll mark this one as answered

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Base R function `exists()` checks if an object is present in the environment, like this `data.frame`

```
> df<- data.frame(a=1:5, b=6:10)
> exists("df")
[1] TRUE
```

It only works for objects, not for their attributes:

```
> exists("df$a")
[1] FALSE
```

Also `exists()` doesn't check they have a value:

```
> nullvar<- NULL
> exists("nullvar")
[1] TRUE
```

So in your example, you can check that object `input` exists :

```
exists("input")
```

But if you want to check that one of its attributes has a value, you have to use `!is.null()`:

```
!is.null(input$select)
```

Comment: Ahh that makes sense. I hadn’t thought through what “input” was, that it’s an object and each of my inputs are attributes thereof. Thanks!